# code displays when i hit submit on my email contact form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my simple contact form to work. When it hit submit to send the email, it just shows code of the next page. So i am thinking it is not the form page but the send_form_email.php. Please help me get this code working, i am not sure what i am missing here. I have tried editing the code to work but it is not changing the output. I have put it in pastebin instead of here because i could not get the code to format correctly. http://pastebin.com/VFN7epGx

```
if(
    !isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])
) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you  submitted.');      

}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
```

//i think it may have to do with this

Comment: I just copied your code and run it on localhost. It works for me with the following values: first_name = John last_name = Doe email = test@example.com telephone = 000111222333 comments = I am a comment!

Comment: If the file shows as plain text it could be that php is not properly configured. Have you confirmed its configuration?

Comment: @Marc is it the version i am probably using ?

Comment: what do you mean by configured correctly? my xampp is running and i have test other php files on my localhost if that is what you mean.

Comment: it shows the code after the echo $error

Comment: Not sure what is going on why it is just showing the code. I did notice something in the code after echo $error then there is . i believe it is concatenation

Comment: someone please help i am desperate

Answer (score 0):

Adding an else statement and using echo instead of dead might help:
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

```
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

!isset($_POST['email']) ||

!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

!isset($_POST['comments'])) {
echo('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

} else {



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
}
```

Sorry fpr the bad formatting, i'm on my phone. Tomorrow I'll look into this on my computer if you didn't fix it yet.

Comment: hey thanks i am still getting string of code to display

Comment: its weird it keeps displaying like this

Answer (score 0):

I can't get at the pastebin as it seems to have been removed, but would personally write it like this - and add preg_replace() code to clean up the inputs. Make sure that nothing has accidentally closed the php tag and that there is no JavaScript hanging around outside of script tags.

```
     if( !isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||  !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
     echo 'We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.';
     }else{
     $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
     $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
     $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
     $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
     $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
     }
```

I like what @T.Somers has done to clean up his inputs on
[PHP Code losing its values when I hit submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711391/php-code-losing-its-values-when-i-hit-submit/33715406#33715406)

and this explains preg_replace quite well

[Regular Expression clean method PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735147/regular-expression-clean-method-php/9735213#9735213)   by @CodeCaster