# PHP Code losing its values when I hit submit

Tags: php

I created this piece of code as part of a practise exercise, however it is not working as intended, I pinpointed the issue to the PHP code losing the values I input via text boxes (The point of the program is to generate a quote for product prices at the end using values from text boxes for the quantities and constants for the actual prices) It then outputs correctly but since it has lost the values all I get is 'Total price = 0'

Anyone got any ideas?
(any comments are there merely for error checking)
I have included my full code in the link below to avoid errors

http://pastebin.com/FpDELpd8

Code from pastebin:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>Validation example
        </head>
<body>
<?php
        //?
        $nameErr = $CustomeremailErr = $MonitorqtyErr = $PCqtyErr = $MiceqtyErr = $KeyboardqtyErr = $SpeakerqtyErr = "";
        $PCqty = $Miceqty = $Keyboardqty = $Monitorqty = $Speakerqty = 0;
        $name = $Customeremail = "";
        DEFINE ("PCPRICE" , 300.01);
        DEFINE ("MONITORPRICE" , 100);
        DEFINE ("KEYBOARDPRICE" , 5);
        DEFINE ("MICEPRICE" , 5);
        DEFINE ("SPEAKERPRICE" , 20);
        DEFINE ("DODGYDELIVERY", 35.05);


        //?
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                        $nameErr = "Name is required";
                } else {
                        $name = clean_input($_POST["name"]);
                        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                                $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
                        }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["customeremail"])) {
                        $customeremailErr = "Email is required";
                } else {
                        $Customeremail = clean_input($_POST["customeremail"]);
                        //check if email is well-formed
                         if (!filter_var($Customeremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                $CustomeremailErr = "Invalid email format";
                        }
                }
                if (empty($_POST["PCqty"])) {
                        $PCqty = clean_input($_POST["PCqty"]);
                } else if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$PCqty)) {
                        $PCqtyErr = "Only Numbers Allowed";
                }
                        if (empty($_POST["Monitorqty"])) {
                        $Monitorqty = clean_input($_POST["Monitorqty"]);
                } else if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Monitorqty)) {
                        $MonitorqtyErr = "Only Numbers Allowed";
                }

                if (empty($_POST["Keyboardqty"])) {
                        $Keyboardqty = clean_input($_POST["Keyboardqty"]);
                        } else if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Keyboardqty)) {
                        $KeyboardqtyErr = "Only Numbers Allowed";
                        }
                if (empty($_POST["Miceqty"])) {
                                $Miceqty = clean_input($_POST["Miceqty"]);
                        } else if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Miceqty)) {
                        $MiceqtyErr = "Only Numbers Allowed";
                        }
                //?Fix change to speaker
                if (empty($_POST["Speakerqty"])) {
                        $Speakerqty = clean_input($_POST["Speakerqty"]);
                } else if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Speakerqty)) {
                        $SpeakerqtyErr = "Only Numbers Allowed";
                }
        }

        // function test_input cleans up data by trimming off blank space, removing slashes and
        //coding characters like < to &lt to prevent hacking
        function clean_input ($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
        }
        ?>

        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">


        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        email: <input type="text" name = "customeremail" value="<?php echo $Customeremail;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $CustomeremailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        PC quantity: <input type="text" name="PCqty" value="<?php echo $PCqty;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $PCqtyErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Keyboard quantity: <input type="text" name="Keyboardqty" value="<?php echo $Keyboardqty;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $KeyboardqtyErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Mice Quantity: <input type="text" name="Miceqty" value="<?php echo $Miceqty;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $MiceqtyErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Speaker Quantity: <input type="text" name="Speakerqty" value="<?php echo $Speakerqty;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $SpeakerqtyErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Monitor Quantity: <input type="text" name="Monitorqty" value="<?php echo $Monitorqty;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $MonitorqtyErr;?></span>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
<?php

$PcTotalCost = $SpeakerTotalCost = $MonitorTotalCost = $MiceTotalCost = $KeyboardTotalCost = 0 ;
// Has this form been submitted and was data entered then do the calculations
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // check there are no errors in the entries

        if (($nameErr == "") && ($CustomeremailErr == "") && ($PCqtyErr == "") && ($MonitorqtyErr == "") && ($MiceqtyErr == "") && ($KeyboardqtyErr == "") && ($SpeakerqtyErr == "") )
         {

                        echo "<h2>Quote</h2>";
                        // Do required calculation
                         $PcTotalCost = $PCqty * PCPRICE;
                        $KeyboardTotalCost = $Keyboardqty * KEYBOARDPRICE;
                        $MonitorTotalCost = $Monitorqty * MONITORPRICE;
                        $SpeakerTotalCost = $Speakerqty * SPEAKERPRICE;
                        $MiceTotalCost = $Miceqty * MICEPRICE;
                        $GoodsTotalCost = $MiceTotalCost + $SpeakerTotalCost + $MonitorTotalCost + $KeyboardTotalCost + $PcTotalCost;
                        $VatRate = $GoodsTotalCost / 100;
                        $GrossCost = $GoodsTotalCost + $VatRate + DODGYDELIVERY;
                        // Displaying the result
                                echo 'Dodgy Dan’s quote for ' . $name . ' on ' . date(1) . "<br/>" ;
                                echo $PCqty . " PC's at a cost of £ ". number_format(PCPRICE, 2) . " each  would cost £ " . number_format($PcTotalCost, 2) . "<br/>";
                                echo $Keyboardqty . " Keyboards at a cost of £ ". number_format(KEYBOARDPRICE, 2) . " each  would cost £ " . number_format($KeyboardTotalCost, 2) . "<br/>";
                                echo $Miceqty . " Mice at a cost of £ ". number_format(MICEPRICE, 2) . " each  would cost £ " . number_format($MiceTotalCost, 2) . "<br/>";
                                echo $Speakerqty . " Speakers at a cost of £ ". number_format(SPEAKERPRICE, 2) . " each  would cost £ " . number_format($SpeakerTotalCost, 2) . "<br/>";     
                                echo $Monitorqty . " Monitors at a cost of £ ". number_format(MONITORPRICE, 2) . " each  would cost £ " . number_format($MonitorTotalCost, 2) . "<br/>";
                                echo " The Delivery charge would be £" . number_format (DODGYDELIVERY, 2) . "<br/>" ;
                                echo ' The total cost of goods is £' . $GoodsTotalCost . "<br/>" ;
                                echo " The VAT(10%)rate for this purchase is £" . $VatRate . "<br/>" ;
                                echo ' The total gross cost after VAT for this order is £' . $GrossCost . "<br/>" ;


                }
        }
?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: this for one thing `[<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is invalid; remove the bracket. and what's this `</html>][1]`?

Comment: and you have a whole bunch of \ one being `$_SERVER\["REQUEST_METHOD"\]` another `$_POST\["name"\]` etc. where they don't belong. So, ask yourself why that is.

Comment: That's interesting, I just went back and checked those aren't there on my version.

Comment: then, do up a pastebin file http://pastebin.com/ with the link to see what you're really using and post it somewhere. Maybe someone will paste it in your question.

Comment: There we go, still rather new at this so thanks

Comment: `if (empty($_POST["Keyboardqty"])) {
                        $Keyboardqty = clean_input($_POST["Keyboardqty"])` if it's empty why sanitize and set the variable?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `if(!empty($_POST...` everywhere.

The exclamation mark is missing, which would mean that he would only get data if the field were empty, as per the comment above "why are you sanitizing empty data?" from @chris85. Hence everything should have if(!empty...

except for

```
     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     if (empty($_POST["customeremail"])){
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10206903)

Comment: The exclamation mark is missing, which would mean that he would only get data if the field were empty, as per the comment above "why are you sanitizing empty data?" from @chris85. Hence everything should have `if(!empty...`